# unable to get JSON data using getJSON method in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use $.getJSON method in knockout.js, but I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error. I am using knockout-3.4.2.js for this project.

Here is my javascript code:

```
// get JSON request of foursquare data
    var reqURL = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + this.position.lat + ',' + this.position.lng + '&client_id=' + clientID + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&v=20160118' + '&query=' + this.title;
    console.log(reqURL);
    $.getJSON(reqURL).done(function(data) {
        var results = data.response.venues[0];
        self.street = results.location.formattedAddress[0] ? results.location.formattedAddress[0] : 'N/A';
        self.city = results.location.formattedAddress[1] ? results.location.formattedAddress[1] : 'N/A';
        self.phone = results.contact.formattedPhone ? results.contact.formattedPhone : 'N/A';
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Something went wrong with foursquare');
    });
```

Html:

```
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <!-- <form class="form-inline"> -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" name="q" data-bind="textInput: searchItem, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
                    <!-- <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            <!-- </form> -->
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: locationList">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bind="text: title, click: show"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/data.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzvsr0e94zenMFlGePE-ywIdt4VoUEy7c&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </body>
```

Please help me get past this error.

Comment: Your script tag which adds `jquery` is commented. Uncomment that and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ is jQuery, so please check whether you include jQuery javascript file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Although I was trying to add jquery, I figured that it was an invalid link. Once I updated with the right link and after uncommenting jquery script tag, of course, it started working.
Updated the code with: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`